# ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed when trying to create a PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, ioexception

I'm working on PDF related project and I want to create a PDF from the existing PDF.

all things are done but when I created a final PDF at that time this exception was thrown at the line of `document.close();` at the method of `savePDF` which describe below.

- Create new PDF from existing PDF adding `PdfImportedPage`.

**here is my code**

**The app crashes only when we add a new page**

```
private void createAndAddPage(Bitmap bitmap) {

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Document document = new Document();
        File file = getPdfFile();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOutputStream); //  Change pdf's name.
        document.open();
        Image image = Image.getInstance(byteArray); // Change image's name and extension.
        float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
                - document.rightMargin() - 0) / image.getWidth()) * 100; // 0 means you have no indentation. If you have any, change it.
        image.scalePercent(scaler);
        image.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(image);
        document.close();

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file.getPath());
        PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
        pageAdjustmentAdapter.AddPage(new PageAjdustAdapter.PdfPage(pdfImportedPage, bitmap));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**method when saves a final PDF(crash happens in this method)**

```
    private void savePDF(PageAjdustAdapter pageAdjustment) {
       
                mPDFpages = pageAdjustment.getUpdatedList();
             
                try {

                    pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new RotateEvent());
                    document.open();

                    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();

                    for (int i = 0; i < mPDFpages.size(); i++) {
                        pdfContentByte.addTemplate(mPDFpages.get(i).page, 0, 0);
                        document.newPage();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: -> " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (document.isOpen()) document.close();
                    actionListener.onEnd("Success");
                
                }

    }
```

**logcat**

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:391)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:103)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.write(OutputStreamCounter.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream.toPdf(PRStream.java:244)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:157)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:402)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:380)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:359)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:854)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReaderInstance.writeAllVisited(PdfReaderInstance.java:160)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReaderInstance.writeAllPages(PdfReaderInstance.java:176)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1368)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1251)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:901)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:415)
    at com.mobilix.docscanner.PageAdjustment$8.run(PageAdjustment.java:233)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Too much steps. Too much code. Nobody can test that out. Please debug further so you only have to post a few lines of code that produce the same exception.

Comment: Still much too much code. Well .. i think. I think you can get the crash too with much less code.  And you should post the relevant logcat lines in a nice code block in your post. (At the moment you are not even mentioning an exception in your post).

Comment: @blackapps question edited.

Comment: You can see in the logcat:  `at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:415)` that at line 415 the document was closed. Then later yopu tried to write. (see first line of logcat).

Comment: But, I never closed the document before write.

Comment: We dont know. We cannot see where and when you call savePdf(). And... still why all that code? Make something that crashes sooner..

Comment: if i write in a closed doc, then why app crash on the `document.close()` line?why not crash on writing function or code?

Comment: I dont know. I'm not trying out your code. I try to help you to debug it. And you should debug with as less code as possible.

Comment: when should I close the pdfwriter?

Comment: In general after all writing done.

Comment: @blackapps I debugged the app but I couldn't find any solution, can you explain what I should do?

Comment: I already told you "less code". For the rest i dont know. And i did not try your code. Probably because there is so much code and it would not be copy/paste to test it i think.

Comment: @blackapps Now code is a less, you can try it.

Comment: @blackapps best direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `createAndAddPage` you import the page into the wrong `PdfWriter`:

```
Document document = new Document();
File file = getPdfFile();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOutputStream); //  Change pdf's name.
document.open();
[...]
document.close();

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file.getPath());
PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
```

Here you import the new page into the `PdfWriter` used for creating that same new page. You instead have to import it into the `PdfWriter` in which you eventually want to use the `pdfImportedPage`.

Comment: Thank you so much! you save my day.